# How can I make a smooth color wheel / spectrum?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I'm currently trying to make a printer test page (see [full code](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/printer-testpage)). One part is a color wheel / RGB-spectrum or however you call this:

[image]

But it has "stripes". I would like to have a smooth color wheel. Is that possible with tikz, too? How?

### Minimal code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[shading=color wheel] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your minimal code [doesn't have any stripes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GeumJ.png). Have you tested with other pdf viewers?

Comment: That's most probably your viewer's fault as it is typical to have rasterized shadings in nonsupporting PDF readers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem of many PDF viewers (thanks to Alenanno and percusse for pointing it out). ImageMagick and Google Chrome showed it how it is supposed to look like.

Where it looks wrong

- pdf2svg ([bug report](https://github.com/db9052/pdf2svg/issues/10))
- Firefox (totally wrong - only showing a pink square; [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1254066))
- Inkscape import ([bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1553990))
- `libpoppler` ([bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94441)) - a bugfix was commited.

  - GIMP import ([bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763214))
  - Okular ([bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360200))
- Atril ([bug report](https://github.com/mate-desktop/atril/issues/188))

Comment: It's not a bug. It's just that the shadings are very new to PDF references. Most viewers do not support it yet by the way.

Comment: @percusse Ok. Hm. I think I'll still add bug reports so that they know that people actually notice (do you know a pointer to the specs? Or the version when it was added?)

Comment: @percusse A follow-up question: When the PDF viewer doesn't display it the right way, could a printer still print it the right way? Or does the PDF viewer always convert it e.g. to EPS?

Comment: Depends on the printer and its drivers. Newish PostScript printers can handle them pretty OK. Some will trip up and others will rasterize. It's really an annoying issue.

Comment: As mentioned in the GIMP bug tracker: might be useful to report this to libpoppler, or check if one of the bugs there already mentions something similar.
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=product:poppler

Comment: As of 2018-03:  Sharelatex PDF viewer shows the color wheel as pink.

Comment: @SDrolet The Sharelatex PDF viewer _is_ your browser (firefox ?).

Comment: @Paul Gaborit  The color wheel is pink in three browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), whereas it is perfectly multicolored when viewing with Preview (iOS 10.13.3) the downloaded PDF produced par Sharelatex.

Comment: @SDrolet With ShareLaTeX, you can choose your PDF viewer: _native_ (my choice) or _built-in_ (default choice). You are right: the _built-in_ PDF viewer of ShareLaTeX shows the color wheel as pink.

Comment: @Paul Gaborit  Until now, I had not noticed that feature of ShareLaTeX. Merci de l'info !